# PSQL connection closing time delay using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, session, sqlalchemy, psql

- Why does there appear to be a significant delay between calling `session.close()` and the session actually closing?
- I'm "using up" connections in a way that doesn't feel right. Is there a better way to do this or a design pattern I'm missing?

Following the guide [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache) I use the following code, copied for completeness:

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()


def run_my_program():
    with session_scope() as session:
        ThingOne().go(session)
        ThingTwo().go(session)
```

This works great for reliably committing data and avoiding invalid sessions.
The problem is with hitting connection limits.

For example, say I have a page that makes 5 asynchronous calls per visit. If I visit the page, and hit refresh in quick succession it will spawn `5 * number_times_refreshed` connections. It will eventually close them but there is a non negligible time delay.

Comment: [Closing a session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#closing) does not close the connection, but returns it to the connection pool, which hands them out to the next session etc. in need. That's the basics of it, but the word "asynchronous" combined with quick refreshes makes it a lot more complicated, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks - I did some more testing locally. Here's an update:
When I run a simple program using the above code the connection is "closed" (at least that's the word used in the log file) as expected - instantly. However, if I have a time.sleep() after the with block it appears to only close the connection after the time.sleep() finishes. Not sure if I'm really missing something here but starting to think it's something else somehow effecting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the use of sessionmaker() and binding the db engine. Specifically this not good way:

```
def newSession():
    engine = create_engine(settings.DATABASE_URL)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    session = DBSession()

    return session

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = newSession()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

This creates a new engine with each request. In addition to this being a poor pattern, it caused confusion on which "connection" was being closed. In this context we have both a "session" and a "DBSession". The session does get closed with session.close() but this does not touch the "DBSession".

**A better way (Solution):**

```
engine = create_engine(settings.DATABASE_URL)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = DBSession()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Creates one connection for the lifetime of the app